# Missing a using directive or an assembly reference for .ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have this code in the class constructor.

```
this._images = images.Split('#').ToList();
```

It has always worked, but now it gives this error:

> Error CS1061  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Did you even try and google this? At all?

Comment: Then obviously you changed something to your code, probably delete the directive `using System-Linq` or compile against .Net 2.0 or prior.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your file

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the using directive for `System.Linq`

Comment: I've already added

But it says that is not necessary...

Comment: @user3465849:- Which .net framework you are using?

Comment: @user3465849:- Also check if you have added the dll reference to your project before using the System.Linq, in this case it would be `System.Core.dll`

Comment: It was that! Thanks!

Comment: @user3465849:- You are welcome!